# How to implement a vertical scrollbar?

Tags: javascript, vis.js, vis.js-timeline

Does anyone know how to implement a vertical scrollbar for a vis.js timeline? I have read the visjs.org documentation, other threads here on stack overflow and on GitHub, but I still can't implement the scrollbar.

Should it be enough to write `verticalScroll: true` in the configuration for a vis.js timeline? This is what I have as configuration at the moment. Do I need to write it in some other way? Or do I need to implement the vertical scroll in a totally different way?

```
// Configuration for the Timeline
var options = {
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    minHeight: '300px',
    padding: '0px',
    orientation: 'top',
    max: futureDate,
    min: pastDate,
    groupOrder: 'start',
    zoomMin: '86400000',
    margin: {item: {horizontal: 0, vertical: 5}, axis: 5},
    verticalScroll: true,
    zoomKey: 'ctrlKey'
};
```

Comment: overflow-y:scroll

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A priori the options taken are good, It would be enough to reduce the height of the timeline directly in the options rather than to use "minHeight" in this case. Normally, this should bring up the scroll bar.

To check this, reduce the timeline height to 150 px  in the options (e.g)
You can also generate a large number of groups so that they exceed the vertical left pannel capacity of timeline so that the vertical scrollbar displays.

UPDATED with minimal example adapted from "[vis.js examples](http://visjs.org/examples/timeline/other/verticalScroll.html)"

See also the timeline [documentation](http://visjs.org/docs/timeline/) on website for configuring options...

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>Timeline | Vertical Scroll Option</title>

    <!-- note: moment.js must be loaded before vis.js, else vis.js uses its embedded version of moment.js -->

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vis/4.21.0/vis.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vis/4.21.0/vis.min.css" />

</head>

<body>

<h1>Timeline vertical scroll option</h1>

<h2>With <code>
verticalScroll: true,
zoomKey: 'ctrlKey'</code>
</h2>

<div id="mytimeline1"></div>

<script>

  // create groups
  var numberOfGroups = 25;
  var groups = new vis.DataSet()
  for (var i = 0; i < numberOfGroups; i++) {
    groups.add({
      id: i,
      content: 'Truck&nbsp;' + i
    })
  }

  // create items
  var numberOfItems = 1000;
  var items = new vis.DataSet();

  var itemsPerGroup = Math.round(numberOfItems/numberOfGroups);

  for (var truck = 0; truck < numberOfGroups; truck++) {
    var date = new Date();
    for (var order = 0; order < itemsPerGroup; order++) {
      date.setHours(date.getHours() +  4 * (Math.random() < 0.2));
      var start = new Date(date);

      date.setHours(date.getHours() + 2 + Math.floor(Math.random()*4));
      var end = new Date(date);

      var orderIndex = order + itemsPerGroup * truck
      items.add({
        id: orderIndex,
        group: truck,
        start: start,
        end: end,
        content: 'Order ' + orderIndex
      });
    }
  }

  // specify options
  var options = {
    stack: true,
    verticalScroll: true,
    zoomKey: 'ctrlKey',
    height: 200, // you can use also "300px"
    start: new Date(),
    end: new Date(1000*60*60*24 + (new Date()).valueOf()),
  };

  // create a Timeline
  var container1 = document.getElementById('mytimeline1');
  timeline1 = new vis.Timeline(container1, items, groups, options);

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried to set the height to 200px and I deleted the minHeight - but still no vertical scrollbar... Is there anything else I could have done wrong??

This is what my configuration option looks like now:

var options = {
        width: '100%',
        height: '200px',
        orientation: 'top',
        max: futureDate,
        min: pastDate,
        groupOrder: 'start',
        zoomMin: '86400000',
        margin: {item: {horizontal: 0, vertical: 5}, axis: 5},
        verticalScroll: true,
        zoomKey: 'altKey'
      };

Comment: @SofiaMalmsten , A fortiori, there is no mistake, at least, I do not see what could go wrong for me.
But I updated my post with a minimal example that you can test anyway.

Comment: Thank you so much @JeanGorene. I had a look at your code and compared it with mine. The issue was not in the configuration options. It was in the references - I had an old version of vis.js.... I have updated it, and everything works perfect now. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you know whether it is possible to have the scroll bar on the right side? I tried to use rtf: true but I'd like to keep the group names on the left hand side and put the scroll bar on the right hand side :)

Comment: @SofiaMalmsten It's probably not impossible to do that, but as far as I know, not directly from the configuration options. Anyway, I don't have a solution right now. Follow this [discussion](https://github.com/almende/vis/issues/4032) on github vis.js issues about the place of the scrollbar (among others).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you can get a scrollbar using `overflow-y: scroll`. Also, `height: 100%` will most likely never cause this to kick in (unless this element is contained within another element that has a set height) as the element that you are editing will keep growing in height rather than staying a certain height and have a scrollbar. So I would recommend removing `height: 100%` and using `max-height` instead (if your element isn't contained within another element), so if the element content grows to something larger than your `max-height`, it will begin to scroll. If you're looking to style that scrollbar, that's a whole different story.

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_overflow-y.asp

Comment: The element is contained within another element, so therefore I used 100%. I tried to set an max height and use overlow-y: scroll.... but that didn't work either. So it won't work at all if I use hight: 100%?

Comment: I thought there was some built in method for vertical scroll in the visjs timelines since there is a configuration option called verticalScroll. Wanted to check how to use that one, since I couldn't make it work

Comment: Ah, this answer isn't valid if you're looking for as vis.js implementation, I took this as an CSS question